# Проверить авторизован ли другой пользователь Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, авторизация, online

Здравствуйте.
В Wordpress есть функция is_user_logged_in(), которая проверяет, авторизован ты сейчас на сайте или нет. Мне же нужна функция, которая будет определять, авторизован ли какой-то другой конкретный пользователь сейчас на сайте, чтобы выводить возле имён авторов что-то вроде статуса "online/offline". Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

> Как это реализовать?

Есть масса готовых плагинов для этого. Напр.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cbxuseronline/screenshots/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-online-users/screenshots/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/online-users-for-user-profiles-made-easy/screenshots/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-useronline/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

Для такого решения вам нужно сделать базу данных (id пользователя (int), Время последнего посещения (datetime)).
В этой базе будем хранить последнее время , когда пользователь был отмечен онлайн.

Добавьте на сайт триггеры онлайн (например обоновление или изменение страницы, периодические аякс запросы, которые будут обновлять время последнего посещения)

Далее, опишите функцию, которая будет брать этого пользователя из базы, по его id и если его последнее посещение не раньше текущего времени, например на 5 минут, то он онлайн.

Таким образом, у нас получится, что если пользователь считается онлайн, если он за последние 5 минут выполнил какое-либо действие.

Comment: Вопрос, вообще-то, про WordPress. Там 2/3 из описанного вами уже в базовом функционале.

Answer (score 0):

Надо записывать в метаполе пользователя состояние его входа/выхода. Код ниже.

```
function action_login($user_login, $user) {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'login_state', 'on');
}
add_action('wp_login', 'action_login', 10, 2);

function action_logout() {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'login_state', 'off');
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'action_logout');
```

В нужном месте страницы читать мета поле 'login_state' и делать ветвление.